# Python code that is unzipping files

Tags: python, performance

I have a small program that is creating a counterpart of existing data files, unzips them and then changes the names of the files. This process runs on a remote desktop server (windows).

**I have one problem:** The runtime of this program is really slow, to create a counterpart of one directory and 1 file, unzip it and change its name it needs  approximately 10 minutes. I have 13 directories and some directories even have multiple files... so I need more then 1 hour to run everything.

**Conclusion:** I need to speed it up, and I would like to know if I can change something about the way my code is written to speed things up.

**Please note:** I cannot use the multiprocessing or multithreading library. I have already tried these libraries out but they wont work with the architecture of the remote desktop server setup. (cannot create multi processors on a remote desktop server)

**This is my code:**

```
data_files = 'c:\data\energy\data_files'
counter_part = 'c:\data\energy\counter_part'
all_missing_dates = ['20210101', '20210102']

    # # # Unzip only the files in in all_missing_dates, create a counterpart of it and add date/change name of the file. 
    pattern = '*.zip'
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_files): 
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern): 
    
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            date_zipped_file_s = re.search('-(.\d+)-', filename).group(1)
            date_zipped_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_zipped_file_s, '%Y%m%d').date()   
            if date_zipped_file_s in all_missing_dates:   
                  
                #Create the counterpart directory 
                new_dir = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.relpath(path, start=data_files), ".."))
    
                #Creae the new counterpart paths
                new = os.path.join(counter_part, new_dir)
    
                #Unzipp the files in the new counterpart location
                if (not os.path.exists(new)):
                    os.makedirs(new)
                zipfile.ZipFile(path).extractall(new) 
            
                
                files = os.listdir(new)
            
                #rename al files in counterpart
                for file in files:
                    filesplit = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
                    if not re.search(r'_\d{8}.', file):
                        os.rename(os.path.join(new, file), os.path.join(new, filesplit[0]+'_'+date_zipped_file_s+filesplit[1]))
    
    print('The files have been processed and transferred to the counter part!')
```

Comment: How many files per directory are we talking about, roughly? For benchmarking purposes.

Comment: @Mast Could be 1 but could also be 5 or 15. Probably not more then 20 or 25.

Comment: This starts being indented halfway though. Please paste EXACTLY your working code